# Is ML.NET supported on ARM64?

Tags: ml.net

Is ML.NET support on ARM64 yet?

If so, can someone provide a link or perhaps some steps to test this on ARM64, please?

thank you!

Comment: .net Core supports it.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I need to install **.NET Core 2.1 or later**.

While ML.NET packages work with both .NET Core 2.1 or later and .NET Framework 4.6.1, only .NET Core 2.1 (starting from the **release 2.1.609**) supports ARMx64 binaries.

**References**

- https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning
- https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1